# Not able to switch Frame in PhantomJS but switches successfully with Firefox using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

The following command runs successfully with Firefox Driver but with PhantomJS I am facing an error message:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

Error Message with PhantomJS:

```
errorMessage":"Unable to switch to frame"
```

Has anyone faced the issue previously and can help me here?

Comment: Can you provide the link/html which you are testing?

Comment: Sorry I cant. And you need VPN to access that anyway.

Comment: Ive tried switching to a frame with the index number which seems to work fine. Using - driver.switchTo().frame(0); / driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(identifier));

Comment: @AmanGupta : Can you post the HTML code snippet of the frame you are trying to switch to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS/GhostDriver has this issue which has been resolved - https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/194

Below statements work with GhostDriver. There is no difference in the statements that have to be used with Ghostdriver.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(frame_index)
driver.switchTo().frame(frame_id)
driver.switchTo().frame(frame_object)
```

Put a wait until the iframe is located

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated("identifier of the frame"))
```

Make sure that the iframe is displayed in the page source.