# Switch frames with selenium and phantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, phantomjs

I need to open the search windows on this page.

https://permits.losgatosca.gov/CitizenAccess/default.aspx

With firefox is working just fine, but when I try to do the same with phantomJS i got an error.

This is the code I'm using to open the search

```
BUTTON_id =  'ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_TabDataList_TabsDataList_ctl01_LinksDataList_ctl00_LinkItemUrl' #'//*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_TabDataList_TabsDataList_ctl01_LinksDataList_ctl00_LinkItemUrl"]/span'
driver_1.switch_to_frame("ACAFrame")
button = driver_1.find_element_by_id(BUTTON_id)
button.click()
```

And this is the error I'm getting with phanthomJS:

```
Message: Error Message => 'Unable to switch to frame'
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385450/not-able-to-switch-frame-in-phantomjs-but-switches-successfully-with-firefox-usi) post it says that using:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(frame_index)
driver.switchTo().frame(frame_id)
driver.switchTo().frame(frame_object)
```

It solves the issue, but I don't know what to put in:

```
frame_index         
frame_id           
frame_object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you should try:

- upgrade both `selenium` and `PhantomJS` to the latest versions
- add a [wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) before switching to frame:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
  wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ACAFrame")))

  driver.switch_to.frame("ACAFrame")
  ```

(worked for me)

Comment: Dis you test it on the page? I'm getting this error: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Screenshot: available via screen

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez yup, worked for me. I had an update in the answer, make sure u have tried the latest version of the answer

Comment: it worked just fine. Is there  a way to optimize​ the waiting time?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez great, how long does it take to wait for the frame to be present?