# How to convert the Selenium with Chrome code into PhantomJS?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I have written some code to scrape a web page using selenium. It is working fine if I use Chrome web driver. But if i change it to `PhantomJS()`, i am getting error saying no such element exception. The code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
s = requests.session()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:\chromedriver')
driver.get("https://in.bookmyshow.com/booktickets/VMAX/2061")
sleep(40)
# To switch to frame
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("wiz-iframe"))

# Clicking on the element inside the frame
e2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='wzrkPPwarp']//a")
e2.click()

# Switching back to main content
driver.switch_to_default_content()

# Then only we can access elements
e3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='No thanks']")
e3.click()
```

This is the code written using Chrome web driver. When i change this to:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

I am getting the error as below:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//div[@class='wzrkPPwarp']//a'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"113","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:56829","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"value\": \"//div[@class='wzrkPPwarp']//a\", \"sessionId\": \"ccc33320-10e5-11e8-b5fa-dbfae1ffdb07\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/ccc33320-10e5-11e8-b5fa-dbfae1ffdb07/element"}}
>       Screenshot: available via screen

How to make it correct? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: `//To switch to frame` is not valid python code.  Please post your actual code.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Maybe the website behaves differently when the browser is not Chrome.  Have you tried printing `driver.page_source` to verify that the desired element is present?

Comment: Have you checked the source of the webpage to make sure the page loads similarly with both Chrome and PhantomJS? It's possible that the site redirects you to a "browser unsupported" type of page if you use PhantomJS

Comment: It is fetching the same html content like the chrome web driver

Comment: If the content is the same, then the code should work.  The only thing I can think of is to add a `wait` call before locating the frame element.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207202/switch-frames-with-selenium-and-phantomjs

Comment: I am making it to wait for 40 seconds. But still, i am getting the same error

Comment: The only further advice I can offer is to double-check the page source to verify that element is present.  Is it spelled __exactly__ the same?

Comment: There are no spelling mistakes. Is it possible to make chrome web driver not shown on the screen while using selenium

Comment: @Thedeadman619 If you mean headless chrome, then yes: https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/